# How to make a navigation from an item of FlatList in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing an APP using React Native now, and I want to make a navigation from every item of a FlatList.

for instance, using [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app). In App.js, the code below:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Text>Changes you make will automatically reload.</Text>
        <Text>Shake your phone to open the developer menu.</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

when I click an item of FlatList, I want to navigate to another component, I code like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  cb() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component: QuestionDetail
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Text>Changes you make will automatically reload.</Text>
        <Text>Shake your phone to open the developer menu.</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text onPress={this.cb.bind(this)}>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

but there is an error.

can anyone how to make an navigator from an item of FlatList? in fact, every item of FlatList should make an navigator when clicked.

thanks!

Comment: are you using react-navigation?

Comment: no, I don't know how to use it. In fact, I want to render a list using FlatList, and when clicking each item, the page will go to another component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using react-navigation (if you want to use react-native-navigation the flow is pretty similar):

Import StackNavigator:

```
imports...
import { Text, View, Button, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

Create your stack of screens/containers:

```
class QuestionDetailScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>QuestionDetail Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to List"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('List')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In your List:

```
class ListScreen extends React.Component {

  cb = () => {
    this.props.navigation.push('QuestionDetail');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Text>Changes you make will automatically reload.</Text>
        <Text>Shake your phone to open the developer menu.</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
          renderItem={({item}) => 
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.cb()}> 
                 <Text>{item.key}</Text> 
             </TouchableOpacity>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And finally export your stacknavigator:

```
const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    List: {
      screen: ListScreen,
    },
    QuestionDetail: {
      screen: QuestionDetailScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'List',
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. In fact, my error is "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push " I think with your code it will result in the same error?

Comment: But what are you using? react navigation? or which one? knowing that we can help you accurately, if you are not sure then try this code put it on your App.js maybe it helps.

Comment: my App.js is above, in fact, I use create-react-native-app as the tempate and add a little code for the demo. I don't use react navigation or others, in fact, I see the code like  `this.props.navigator.push({component: QuestionDetail});` in others' code of App, its feature is jump to another component, but I meet the error, and others say I should add some code like `{...props}` to the root element, but it does not work too. I am new to React Native, so what I describe may be really confusing. sorry for that

Comment: my goal is really simple, use FlatList, and when I click each item of the FlatList, I can navigate to another component, that's what I want

Comment: Well in order to access to this.props.navigator or this.props.navigation you should use a navigator component "I don't use react navigation or others" so how do you pretend to navigate in your app? [this post may help you to understand navigation](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/thousand-ways-to-navigate-in-react-native-f7a1e311a0e8) :)

Comment: one more, so what's the easiest way to make a navigation?

Comment: The easiest way I think It will be up to you, but the one I like and currently using is [react-native-navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/) since I use redux I feel it makes things easier, as well I feel it's better in performance and stability but as I said it's totally up to you, and the example in my answer was done using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) but in my opinion RNN it's better and easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  cb() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component: QuestionDetail
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Text>Changes you make will automatically reload.</Text>
        <Text>Shake your phone to open the developer menu.</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
          renderItem={({item}) => 
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.cb()}> 
                    <Text>{item.key}</Text> 
                </TouchableOpacity>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

You can call the navigation function i.e `cb()` using a arrow function. 
I have used a `TouchableOpacity` to give the text element `onPress` functionality.

Comment: thanks, I test your code, the same error, undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push